# Why am I missing the result of a smoothing effect in a GAMM while interpreting results from summary command

Tags: r, modeling, mgcv

I have been using GAMMs to analyze time series data and I have included a smoothing term (hour of day by season) and I can't seem to find the results for the winter season. I have the proper information (edf, Ref.df, F, and p-value) for all my smoothed terms and each season except for winter. I am using the summary function and calling on the gam results within the model (instead of the lme summary output).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is Winter the first factor level? if so it is included in the intercept

Comment: Just remove the `s(hour)` term and `s(hour):seasonWinter)` should appear in the output.

Comment: @Roland - I just tried removing the s(hour) term in the model and it still isnt providing the s(hour):seasonWinter output.

Comment: @AlexJ - I am trying to get the s(hour):seasonWinter output to find the signifignace of the smooth terms, instead of the fixed effects outputs in the parametric coefficients section.

Comment: @KevinShort I can't see the code output anymore that I think you included before, but - a normal `lm` with a categorical predictor will have the first category "hidden" in the intercept. I suspect that's what is happening here, but I will need more information to see. A `str( )` of the relevant part of the data, and a summary of model results would be good.